# Order of conjugacy class divides order of group

Tags: group-theory

I was reading this proof:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Conjugates_is_Number_of_Cosets_of_Centralizer

and I don't understand the very last part, why the order of the conjugacy class divides the order of the group. It says that it follows by Lagrange's but the conjugacy class is not necessarily a subgroup? I'm thinking that perhaps the index of the centralizer is exactly equal to the order of some subgroup of $G$, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange the order of the centralizer divides the order of the group. The number of conjugacy classes is the number of cosets of the centralizer, which is the same as the index of the centralizer. This is a divisor of the order of the group because it is the order of the group divided by the order of the centralizer.

Comment: I know, but lagrange's only says the order of the centralizer divides the order of the group. Why does this mean the number of cosets of the centralizer divides it as well?

Comment: @b_pcakes Edited further explanation. Alan Wang's answer says the same, but with notation.

Comment: Hm, this the case because the centralizer is a normal subgroup?

Comment: No; in general if $d$ is a divisor of $n$, then $\tfrac{n}{d}$ is also a divisor of $n$, because $d\cdot\tfrac{n}{d}=n$.

Comment: I mean, where you said "it is the order of the group divided by the order of the centralizer". The number of cosets of a subgroup is not necessarily equal to order of the group divided by the order of the subgroup unless the subgroup is normal, is it? Because the left cosets don't necessarily have same cardinality then

Comment: Oops nvm! It is

Answer (score 3):

Since $|C_a|=[G:C_G(a)]$, if $G$ is a finite group, we have $$|C_a|=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(a)|}$$
$$|G|=|C_a||C_G(a)|$$
So obviously, $|C_a|$ divides $|G|$

Maybe the proof there wants to mean that the index of a subgroup $[G:H]$ divides $|G|$.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are lost among words (like I was), there is a very natural one to one correspondance between the cosets of the centralizer and the conjugacy class. $\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}$

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g\in G$ and $H$ be the centralizer of $g$ in $G$ i.e., $H=C_G(g)$.

We want to show that size of the conjugacy class of $g$ i.e., $|\cl(g)|$ is given by the number of left cosets in the partition $G/H$. (Mind that I have not called it a quotient group.)

We can exhibit a mapping $f:G/H\to \cl(g)$ defined by $f(kH)=kgk^{-1}$ i.e., a left coset $kH$ maps to conjugate $kgk^{-1}$ of $g$.

This mapping is obviously onto because every conjugate of $g$ is of the form $kgk^{-1}$ whence, $kH$ is a pre-image.

Show that $f$ is well-defined, one-one and hence, it is bijective.

$\begin{align}&f(aH)=f(bH)\\ \iff & aga^{-1}=bgb^{-1}\\ \iff & (b^{-1}a)g=g(b^{-1}a)\\ \iff &b^{-1}a\in H \\ \iff & b^{-1}aH=H\\ \iff & aH=bH \end{align}\tag*{}$

Check the steps:

- top to bottom (conclude one-one) and
- bottom to top (conclude well-defined).

Hence, $f$ is a bijection and $|\cl(g)|=|G/H|=|G|/|H|$. $\blacksquare$

Now, $|\cl(g)|\cdot |H|= |G|$ 
 $\implies |\cl(g)|$ divides $|G|$.